# Javascript calendar in master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I used the example from here [MasterCalendar](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/CalendarWIthMasterPage10062008043352AM/CalendarWIthMasterPage.aspx#ReadAndPostComment)

But this works fine in IE where as in mozila it does not work i tried as he said by naimg with the control id then the selected date is not getting displayed so can any one give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi user just change the `YearRange` as follows

```
       yearRange: 'c-100:c+0'
```

It will display from `1911-2011` if needed change `c-100` values as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery UI datepicker instead of that

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

cheers!

Comment: Hi i used this as my requirement is to select year and month from drop down [link]http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html` but it is only displaying 10 years at a time but i need all how can i